# Server does not data from client

Tags: java, netty

I'm implementing a basic UDP server and client.

the server and the client are running on a same computer.

Please, don't mind grammar or spelling error on the code because it's not copy & paste.

1 Client,

```
public void sendData() {
  Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
  b.option(ChannelOption.SO_BROADCAST, true);
  b.channel(NioDatagramChannel.class);
  b.handler(new LogSenderHandler());

  Channel channel = b.bind(9002).sync.channel();
  channel.writeAndFlush(new DatagramPacket(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("test", CharsetUtils.UTF_8), SocketUtils.socketAddress("localhost", 9001))).sync();
  channel.closeFuture().await();
}
```

2 Server.

```
 public void run(){
  Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
  b.channel(NioDatagramChannel.class);
  b.option(ChannelOption.SO_BROADCAST, true);
  b.handler(new LogServerHnalder());

  Channel channel = b.bind(9001).sync.channel();

  channel.closeFuture().await();
 }
```

3 LogServerHandler

```
public class LogServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket> {
  @Override
  protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket msg) throws Exception {
    /*   some code...... */
  }
}
```

I expect LogServerHandler.channelRead() to be excuted when I call Client.run().
However LogServerHandler.channelRead() never excuted.

Comment: You have to run client and server separately

Comment: @Steephen do you mean that I have to run server and client on different computer??

Comment: You can run server and client either on same or different computer. But you have to invoke server first and client next independently